Why is the density at the point $(x,y)$, equal to $\frac{dm}{dA}$?
I was reading this MSE post, and here is part of @Kman3's answer:

Mass
Imagine a lamina with constant density, $\rho$. The mass $m$ of the
lamina and the area $A$ occupied by the lamina are in equal
proportion. $1/4$ of the lamina has $1/4$ of the mass of the lamina,
and so on. Now, what happens when the density isn't constant? This is
what calculus was built for.
$\color\red{\text{Say the density changes from point to point within a certain lamina.}}$
$\color\red{\text{We can say that at a position $(x,y)$, the density $\rho(x,y)$ can be
 expressed as}}$
$$\color\red{\rho(x,y)=\frac{dm}{dA}}$$
Now, to find the total mass of the object, we can integrate density
with respect to volume:
$$dm = \rho(x,y) \  dA$$
$$m= \iint_R \rho(x,y) \ dA$$
So now that we have mass covered, let us define moments.

I didn't completely understand the part of the text that I colored as red. I know that the formula for density in general is $\rho=\dfrac mV$, and in the case of very thin lamina $V\approx A$. What I didn't understand is this: If the density is a function of point and changes from point to point, why is the density at a given point is equal to $\dfrac {dm}{dA}$?

I would suggest you take it as a definition. In most cases, though, it's formed in a tad different way as follows. Suppose you have any kind of an object with a peculiar mass distribution. Since the latter is an integral characteristic, it is usually inconvenient to be described, as opposed to some differential characteristic. Hence, you create a special function that relates the tiniest bit of your mass $\mathbb{d}m$ with its however defined size $\mathbb{d}V$ via $$\mathbb{d}m = \rho(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) \, \mathbb{d}V.$$
It becomes quite handy now because you may do that not only for mass, but for any integral property of a physical object and in whatever construct.
